# is there any other ways to perform Copy and paste action in selenium using python without affecting other operation?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

`driver.find_element(By.ID,"email").send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "a");`
`driver.find_element(By.ID,"password").send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "c");`
`driver.find_element(By.ID,"password").send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "v");`

Due to this copy paste operation, I can't perform any other copy paste operation through out this system while performing this task.

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't know exactly where the element text is, I gave an example assuming it is between the  tags. We can help you better if you provide information about the page source.

Except sending keys, you can get the element text with the selenium and copy it to system clipboard by using subprocess library;

```py
import subprocess
def copy2clip(txt):
        cmd = 'echo ' + txt.strip() + '|clip'
        return subprocess.check_call(cmd, shell=True)

content = driver.find_element(By.ID,"email").get_attribute("innerHTML")
copy2clip(content)
```